# Spaces when converting byte array to hex std::string c++

Tags: c++, string, encoding, hex, crypto++

I am using the following function to convert a byte array (Crypto++ key) to a Hex String

```
std::string Hexa::byte_to_hex_encoder(unsigned char *array, int len){
    std::stringstream ss;
    for(int i=0;i<len;++i)
        ss << std::hex << std::uppercase <<std::setw(2) <<(int)array[i];
    return ss.str();
}
```

The byte array is of size 16 and when I don't use `setw(2)` I get a hex string with lesser characters like 30 or sometimes 31. When I am using `setw(2)` I get random spaces in the hex string like

> 5CA0 138C5487D2C6D929EC36B694890

How can I convert a byte array to hex string and vice versa without spaces in the hex string?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642079/c-hex-string-to-byte-array and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050452/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-visual-c

Comment: You can make a "?" if you press shift, and "." . Good luck, wonderful Viraj! :-)

Comment: great job, but shift and "." gives you >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need `setfill('0')` so that the numbers are properly padded.

Without the `setw`, a number like 7 comes out as just `7`, making your string short as you have seen. With the `setw` but no `setfill`, it's padded to the right *length,* but with a space.

Adding the `setfill` ensures it gets padded with zeroes.

For your code that would be:

```
ss << std::hex
   << std::uppercase
   << std::setw(2)
   << std::setfill('0')
   << (int)array[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the Crypto++ tag, here's are two ways to do it in Crypto++. From the [HexEncoder](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Hexencoder) wiki page.

First, using Crypto++ [pipelines](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipeline):

```
byte decoded[] = { 0xFF, 0xEE, 0xDD, 0xCC, 0xBB, 0xAA, 0x99, 0x88,
                   0x77, 0x66, 0x55, 0x44, 0x33, 0x22, 0x11, 0x00 };
string encoded;

StringSource ss(decoded, sizeof(decoded), true,
    new HexEncoder(
        new StringSink(encoded)
    ) // HexEncoder
); // StringSource

cout << encoded << endl;
```

As with the previous example, a run produces the following output.

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe
FFEEDDCCBBAA99887766554433221100
```

---

And second, using functions:

```
byte decoded[] = { 0xFF, 0xEE, 0xDD, 0xCC, 0xBB, 0xAA, 0x99, 0x88,
                   0x77, 0x66, 0x55, 0x44, 0x33, 0x22, 0x11, 0x00 };
string encoded;

HexEncoder encoder;
encoder.Put(decoded, sizeof(decoded));
encoder.MessageEnd();

word64 size = encoder.MaxRetrievable();
if(size)
{
    encoded.resize(size);       
    encoder.Get((byte*)encoded.data(), encoded.size());
}

cout << encoded << endl;
```

A run of the above program produces the following output.

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe
FFEEDDCCBBAA99887766554433221100
```

---

There's a [HexDecoder](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexDecoder) too so you can decode the encoded strings. It works nearly the same way.

Comment: I did not find a way to convert from a Hex string to byte array so decided against using the inbuilt encoder/decoder. Is there method to convert to a byte array ?